# Screen goes blank after undocking

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, dell, laptop, screen

For some reason since yesterday completely working system can't work without dockstation: screen goes blank, but everything else works.

I still can login as guest and everything will work fine, or switch with ctrl-alt-fsomething to terminal session, but as soon as I start session(with xstart, for example) with my user after appearance of the first icon in the default kubuntu bootloader screen goes blank.

I thought the issue might have been in external monitor, but even if I turn it off in "Displays" and leave only notebook screen it still goes blank after undocking.

The only difference yesterday was replacement of external monitor, but I can't see how this may change anything.

Kubuntu 14.04, Dell - Latitude E6330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to help me-from-the-past to fix this:

Dear me! You should read about xrandr, because this is simple terminal-operated program to work with screens.

For some reason configuration after undocking has bugged and you have to turn on laptop's screen manually from xrandr for once and then everything will be well.

Comment: thanks. I ran these two commands and after that, the problem seems to be fixed: ```xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 800x600``` and to bring back the proper resolution ```xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080``` (you can list all your screens and available resolution with ```xrandr```)